# PHP Symbol Table

Tags: php, symbol-table

According to the image description, when the second value of the array is changed using one of its two references, the array's reference counting the symbol table is set to 1.The reason for this is that a new array was allocated in memory after the second value was changed using one of the references. However, I wonder if this could happen to variables referencing scalar primitives such as integers, floating-point numbers, Strings, and Booleans or is it only limited to compound primitives such as arrays?

[image]

Comment: No. Only arrays passed to functions are copied on write access. But if you want [weak references](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.weakreference), you can create them, i.e. for caching purpose.

Comment: You should not use images, where text would suffice.  Please edit your question and copy/paste the text.  And you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask